# How do I disable edge selection only in JGraphX?

Tags: java, swing, selection, edges, jgraphx

I'm trying to disable edge selection only in JGraphX. If I call

```
mxgraph.setCellsSelectable(false);
```

This disables selection on all cell, not just edges. Is there something like a `setEdgesSelectable`()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override:

```
public boolean isCellsSelectable()
```

in an mxGraph subclass and use that sub-class. By default that returns `mxgraph.cellsSelectable`. You want something like (not tested at all):

```
public boolean isCellsSelectable()
{
    if (model.isEdge())
    {
        return false;
    }

    return cellsSelectable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of today, the current JGraphX version (3.6) doesn't have the `isCellsSelectable()` method mentioned in David's answer, but basically the solution stays the same.

You need just to use the `isCellSelectable(Object cell)` method as shown below:

```
public boolean isCellSelectable(Object cell)
{
    if (model.isEdge(cell))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return super.isCellSelectable(cell);
}
```